# Dynamically changing ToolTipDialog content

Tags: javascript, tooltip

My application has a list of indicators, each with its help button. Clicking on each button, brings up a ToolTipDialog with definition for each respectively. The way I have written the code (below), the content does not get refreshed when the user clicks on another help button within the list after having clicked the first one. I have not been able to figure out how to change the "content" dynamically. Any help will be appreciated:

HTML:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="group1" title="Population projection" selected="true">
<table id="popIndTable">
<tr id="someID">
<td><input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.RadioButton" class="checkInd" id="checkCBR" name="checkInd" /></td>
<td id="indCBR">Crude Birth Rate</td>
<td id="infoCBR"><img id="imgCBR" src="Images/help_icon2.png"  width="16px" onClick="showToolTipDialog(this,this.id);" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.RadioButton" class="checkInd" id="checkTest1" name="checkInd" /></td>
<td id="indTest1">Test 1</td>
<td id="infoTest1"><img id="imgTest1" src="Images/help_icon2.png"  width="16px" onClick="showToolTipDialog(this,this.id);" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.RadioButton" class="checkInd" id="checkTest2" name="checkInd" /></td>
<td id="indTest2">Test 2</td>
<td id="infoTest2"><img id="imgTest2" src="Images/help_icon2.png"  width="16px" onClick="showToolTipDialog(this,this.id);" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showToolTipDialog(node,infoId){
var infoText;
var infoElem = dojo.byId(infoId).parentNode.id;
if (infoElem == "infoCBR"){
infoText = "This is the text container for CBR";
}
else if (infoElem == "infoTest1"){
infoText = "This is the text container for Test1";
}
if (!tooltipDialog) {
tooltipDialog = new dijit.TooltipDialog({
content: infoText,
style: "width:200px;height:auto;",
autofocus: !dojo.isIE, // NOTE: turning focus ON in IE causes errors when reopening the dialog
refocus: !dojo.isIE
});
dijit.popup.open({ popup: tooltipDialog, around: node});
tooltipDialog.opened_ = true;
}
else {
if (tooltipDialog.opened_) {
dijit.popup.close(tooltipDialog);
tooltipDialog.opened_ = false;
}
else {
dijit.popup.open({popup: tooltipDialog, around: node});
tooltipDialog.opened_ = true;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you never reset the content of your tooltipDialog.  You create it once, but once it's created (`new dijit.TooltipDialog({...})`) it remains static.

I don't know the Dojo API.  But can you just set the content value directly?  Perhaps immediately after your first `else`:

```
tooltipDialog.content = infoText;
```

This is just a guess, but if Dojo's API is simple enough, that might do the trick.

If not, you might have to remove your `if (!tooltipDialog) {` check.

Comment: Thanks Scott,I did try the code by removing "if.." but it did not help with my issues.

Comment: Did you try my main suggestion?  That would be better in any case.

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work for me. I am rethinking the logic of the code and might make some changes to it. But I'll be happy to try other alternatives, if any.

Comment: I would definitely want to change the logic in general, and store the tooltip content as the title attribute of the appropriate DOM node and extract it from there.  There are many tooltip libraries that work this way.  Even if you don't want to use them, you might look at how they manage to get it working.

Comment: I tried this and it worked. I destroyed the tooltipDialog if it already existed and placed it after my second 'else'. At this point I created a new tooltipDialg with the new infoText.

Comment: Well congratulations!  If you have time, do look at some of the other implementations, especially those that store the content on the DOM.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the preferred way to change the value of a dojo widget programatically is to use the .set() method. ie:

```
this.myTooltipDialog.set("content", newContent);
```

Rather than:

```
this.myTooltip.content = newContent;
```

Answer (score -1):

If your content is not too complicate, I suggestion you create a new TooltipDialog every call and clear it when blur, like

```
var dlgDiv = dojo.create("div");
var dlg = new dijit.TooltipDialog({
    content: dlgDiv,
    onBlur: function () {
        popup.close(this);
        this.destroyRecursive();
    }
});

// you can create any content within dlgDiv at here dynamicly

dojo.popup.open({
    around: yourArondNode  ,
    orient: ["below", "before", "after", "above"],
    popup: dlg
});
dlg.focus();
```

Comment: expensive answer and unnecessary